# List files that have the same first 16 characters

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I want to write a bash script that I can run in a directory and that will do the following:

- Go through all subdirectories (recursively)
- If there are two files *in the same given subdirectory* whose filenames have the same first 16 characters (e.g. "YourTestFileNameHey.jpg" and "YourTestFileNameFoo.png"), output their file names (or move one of them to a different location).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: start by reading these man pages `find` `sort` (sort, and sort uniques) `diff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will do the job for you, but you can base yourself on the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$1"
for i in *; do j=`echo $i | cut -c 1-16`; echo $1/$i\|$j;done | awk -F\| 'seen[$
2]++ == 1 { printf("echo \"%s\"", $1) | "sh" }'
```

It will list every second file that has the same first 16 characters as another file in the same directory. You could easily replace the echo command inside printf("echo \"%s\"", $1) by a mv command.

Now, if you want to use this script in all subdirectories under a specific directory, let's call it mydir, you could do that with the find command like this, assuming you saved the above script in a file called myscript which resides in the same directory as mydir:

```
find mydir -type d -exec ./myscript {} \;
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favor and use something else than bash for a task that complex. My own first choice would be Perl, but if you know *any* general-purpose programming language, it will be easier and more maintainable there than in pure shell.